# Basic question about hybridization

Tags: hybridization

I just started a basic course on chemistry and we are going really fast (at least for me).

During the last lesson our teacher left us with a question: "What is hybridization and how it relates to hund principle?"

Now I know from the slides what hybridization is and what the hund principle says, but for me they are not related. What I mean is that the hund principle state one thing and the hybridization states another thing, they are similar, but I wouldn't say that they are related.

A couple of details on what I've understood:
Hund principle: every orbital is first occupied by one electron before any one orbital is filled doubly occupied with an electron of opposite spin (like wikipedia say)
Hybridization is the mixing of a set of atomic orbital with sligtly different energy, that forms a new set of orbitals (also taken from internet/slides)

Are those definitions correct? can they be explained in a better way?
why and how they are related if they are?
PS remember that I'm a noob in this subject

Comment: Hybridization occurs in our heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an example will help your understanding. Consider methane, $\ce{CH4}$, which is a common example when discussing hybridization. First, think about the electronic configuration of the central atom, carbon. It is in group 4A, which corresponds to four valence electrons. Carbon is a p-block element, which means its valence electrons are distributed between its S and P orbitals. You can write this out yourself by recalling the periodic trends you should be learning by now.

[image: Carbons electron configuration1]

As you can see from the nifty graphic, Hund's rule tells us that despite carbon having four valence electrons, in its ground state (another way of saying its "normal state"), carbon appears to only have 2 valence electrons available for bonding. If carbon has only two electrons are available for bonding, such that only two bonds may form, how in the world do we have molecules like $\ce{CH4}$ floating around? This is where hybridization comes into play. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation), Linus Pauling first suggested the idea that orbitals may hybridize (mix) into degenerate orbitals (orbitals with the same level of energy) so that bonding may occur. In other words, the S and P orbitals rearrange themselves in terms of equal energy (or at least near equal) so that carbon can create bonds in order to obtain a full octet of electrons.

[image: Carbon sp3 hybridization]

Now it should be clear that we have the four electrons necessary to form covalent bonds like the ones we see in methane. Keep in mind, hybridization is a way to represent how atomic orbitals arrange themselves to promote bonding when the occasion rises. Hund's rule tells us how to organize electrons that end up in those orbitals, and shows us why the concept of hybridization is needed in the first place.

Comment: That second figure is just wrong. If you have atomic orbitals that are solutions to the time-independent Schrödinger equation with different eigenvalues (energies), then mixing those orbitals together does not any longer satisfy the time-independent SE. In other terms, hybrid orbitals do not have defined energies.

Comment: @Antimon I think you're missing the point of the explanation. If you have a problem with the image, you can argue with its creators (https://courses.lumenlearning.com/chemistryformajors/chapter/hybrid-atomic-orbitals/.) I don't think I made a statement about hybrid orbitals having exactly defined energies, other than that we can conceptually consider them degenerate, despite the idea of hybridization just being a tool to rationalize orbital mixing. I don't doubt your point, but it's not relevant to a student who is just beginning to learn chemistry, and only functions to obfuscate.

Comment: But why use an "explanation" if it is wrong anyway? Hybridization is about as correct as the Bohr model. We're not doing anyone a favour by leaning into outdated or oversimplified models only to have students unlearn them at a later stage (or, even worse, never). At the very least, it warrants a big "Don't actually believe this" disclaimer.

Comment: @Antimon  I suppose your issue is with many academic and educational institutions and what they teach, rather than the actual question here. I don't know how to help you. Write a letter to someone important I guess. Nevertheless, many outdated and unhelpful things are still taught in introductory chemistry. It's true, many things have to be rearranged and many ideas clarified later into a chemistry degree. I totally agree with you on this. But this is true in every field. Unfortunately we can't guarantee that every premed student taking intro chemistry class needs to learn quantum mechanics.